# Inverse Kirby knot

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, blow-ups, quantum-topology, kirby-calculus

Given an (oriented framed) knot $K$ in the 3-sphere $S^3$, we can perform a surgery along $K$ to get another 3-manifold $M$. From $M$, we can perform the inverse surgery back to $S^3$.

However, the data we need for the second surgery is just a framed knot $K'$ in $M$, which could have come from another knot $K''$ in $S^3$ before any surgery has been performed. In this case, $K \cup K''$ must be Kirby equivalent to the empty knot because surgery only it is trivial. Therefore, I call $K''$ an **inverse Kirby knot** of $K$.

Curiously, while the procedure above is straightforward, I don't see an easy way to construct $K''$ directly from a knot presentation of $K$!

1. How to write down a knot presentation of $K''$ from that of $K$?
2. Is such $K''$ unique up to Kirby moves?
3. What if we start from a link $L$ in $S^3$ instead of a knot?

---

**EDIT** According to Danny Ruberman's comment below, the dual knot can be regarded as what I call an inverse Kirby knot.

Answer (score 12):

The standard model for the knot $K''$ you describe is simply the meridian $\mu_K$ of the knot $K$. To be a bit pedantic, this really means that you draw the meridian in the complement of $K$, and then take its image in the surgered manifold. Is this perhaps what you mean by *construct $K''$ directly from a knot presentation of $K$*?. Since $K''$ is a knot in some $3$-manifold (ie the surgery on $K$) then it's also not clear to me what `knot presentation' means.  The framing on $K''$ to get back to $S^3$ is determined by the pushoff of $\mu$ that links $\mu$ zero times.  The same observations would work for links.

If $Y$ is obtained from $S^3$ by surgery on two distinct knots, say $K_1$ and $K_2$, then each of those would give rise to knots $K_1''$ and $K_2''$ in $Y$ such that surgery along those two knots give back $S^3$. There are many examples of $3$-manifolds with multiple knot surgery descriptions, and presumably the knots $K_1''$ and $K_2''$ would be distinct as knots in $Y$.

The oldest examples I know of manifolds with more than one knot surgery description are due to Brakes, *Manifolds with multiple knot-surgery descriptions*. Proc. Cambridge Phil. Soc.
**87** (1980), 443-448.

Comment: I thought that must be the solution.. but I can not even Kirby-move $K \cup K''$ back to the empty knot for $K$ being a trefoil.. In general, for each knot $K$, do you expect it to be easy to find a Kirby movie that transform $K \cup K''$ to null, if $K''$ is taken as you suggested?

Comment: Yes, this is standard. If you want to stay in the $3$-dimensional world, you can move $\mu$ next to any crossing of $K$, and then slide over $\mu$ to change the crossing. Repeat until you have a Hopf link with one $0$-framed component, and it's standard that this is $S^3$. (See Proposition 3 in Kirby's original paper.) From a $4$-dimensional perspective, you can do the surgery on $\mu$ first, and view the resulting $S^1 \times S^2$ as the boundary of $B^4$ plus a $1$-handle. Then the $2$-handle added along $K$ cancels that $1$-handle, leaving $B^4$. All of this is in Gompf-Stipsicz.

Comment: Very useful! I can now convince myself with a mixture of 3- and 4- perspective. The key lies in the "2-handle slide" given in figure 5.11 of Gompt-Stipsicz. However, given that Kirby moves can be generated by 1-blowup and 1-blowdown, there should be a way to prove that "2-handle slide" in a pure 3- perspective using blow-up/down. It isn't clear though.. and I think that's my blind-spot. Do you happen to have a picture of how to prove that handle-slide by only using blow-up/down?

Comment: Well, handle slides can be viewed from a purely 3-dimensional viewpoint: move a portion of one solid torus into the other and watch it come out the other side.  (See proofs of the so-called slam-dunk move for this sort of argument.) If you like you can look at the paper of Fenn-Rourke that shows how to rewrite a handle slide in terms of blowing up/down. But I'd really suggest getting more familiar with the 4-dimensional viewpoint.

Comment: I understand the clarity of the 4-d viewpoint, but just want to understand it in a 3-d viewpoint. It might hint at some mysterious details about a certain 3d tqft. I have checked the original paper by Fenn and Rourke, but the description there isn't clear to me how to do a 2-handle slide using blow-ups and blow-downs..

Comment: By the way, the knot $K''$ in $S^3_n(K)$ (the surgered manifold) is often called the dual knot to $K$.